# how can i use 64 bits inline assembly in c?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, 64-bit

```
int main(void) {
unsigned long long a = 0x0ab0000000234432;
unsigned long long b = 0x0000000000000001;
unsigned long long c = 0x0000000032123001;
unsigned long long r1;

__asm__ __volatile__(
    "mov    %1, %%eax   \n\t"
    "xor    %2, %%eax   \n\t"
    "xor    %3, %%eax   "
    : "=&a" (r1)
    : "g" (a), "g" (b), "g"(c));

for(i=63; i>=0; i--) {
    printf("%d ", (r1 >> i) & 1 );
    if (i%8 == 0) printf(" ");
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

binary value is that 
a = 00001010 10110000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00100011 01000100 00110010 
b = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 
c = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110010 00010010 00110000 00000001

I want to get 00001010 10110000 00000000 00000000 00110010 00110001 01110100 00110010 for result.
but, result is 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110010 00110001 01110100 00110010

I think the code is compiled by 32bits mode. 
I use MAC OS X, intel CPU and GCC.

how can i use 64bits inline assembly

Comment: `eax` is a 32-bit register. It's the lower 32 bits of the 64-bit `rax` register.

Comment: Use `gcc -m64` to make absolutely sure that your code is compiled in 64-bit mode. (There is the corresponding `gcc -m32` as well.)

Comment: Your code formatting is terrible, and the original code you have posted contained many syntax errors (e.g. missing `}` at the end of the program). I've fixed most of these obvious error in the code in the question for you. Please take the effort and post working code as is. Please follow http://sscce.org/ . Please double check and explicitly state that the code you've posted compiles cleanly (i.e. without warnings with `gcc -W -Wall -Wextra`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `eax` register. It's only 32 bits. Use `rax`.

Answer (score 5):

Following on to Greg's answer which warranted upvoting, you are attempting to use `32-bit` registers `eax` and wanting to stuff `64-bits` into them. You can't. X86_x64 assembler is an extension to 32-bit assembly (but numerous addons). For purposes here, register size was increased from `32-bit` to `64-bit` and the registers were also **renamed**. Just as `16-bit` registers were increased to `32-bit` and renamed `ax` to `eax`, with the increase to `64-bit`, the registers were again renamed `eax` to `rax`. Those are the only changes needed. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    unsigned long long a = 0x0ab0000000234432;
    unsigned long long b = 0x0000000000000001;
    unsigned long long c = 0x0000000032123001;
    unsigned long long r1;
    int i = 0;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov    %1, %%rax   \n\t"
        "xor    %2, %%rax   \n\t"
        "xor    %3, %%rax   "
        : "=&a" (r1)
        : "g" (a), "g" (b), "g"(c));

    for(i=63; i>=0; i--){

        printf("%d", (int)(r1 >> i) & 1 );

        if(i%8 == 0 ) printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
00001010 10110000 00000000 00000000 00110010 00110001 01110100 00110010
```